# How to bind an indexer to a GridViewColumn in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my `ViewModel` object I have a this indexer like:

```
public bool this[enum effectType]
{
    get { return CheckList.First ( e => e.EffectType == effectType ).IsChecked; }
}
```

but not sure how to bind this in Xaml. I have tried these:

```
<GridViewColumn
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox
                IsChecked="{Binding Item[Blur], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

IsChecked="{Binding this[Blur], Mode=TwoWay}"/>

IsChecked="{Binding AllEffects[Blur], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

`AllEffects` is an `ObservableCollection` already binded to the `ListBox` itself and the columns are already populated except the checked ones which I am trying to bind to this indexer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding .[Blur], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Please note that your indexer property must provide a setter in order `TwoWay` binding to work.

Comment: Thanks Pavlo, it works great. I was gonna add the setter after I solve this issue. Btw just to learn, if I had a indexer property like NewItems, then would the binding be Binding NewItems[Blur], instead of the `.`?